# Stop Visual Studio debugging in C# code

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've got some code to shutdown an application. However if I'm running the application in Visual Studio and debugging, I want to stop debugging and not shutdown my computer. Any suggestions:

code:

```
#if DEBUG
            throw new Exception("Can't shutdown!");
#else
            try
            {
                this.Shutdown();
            }
            finally
            {
                Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-r -f -t 0");
            }
#endif
```

Comment: Does the if work? then you can just application.exit that will stop the debugging

Comment: Your current approach seems to work. What don't you like about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
if (Debugger.IsAttached)
    throw new Exception("Can't shutdown!");
else
    try
    {
        this.Shutdown();
    }
    finally
    {
        Process.Start("shutdown.exe", "-r -f -t 0");
    }
```

Comment: That helps me identify when a debugger is used, which I could do before with `#if DEBUG`, however, how can I stop debugging without shutting down my system?

Comment: By exiting your application instead of throwing an exception. _(like EpicKip said)_ The `#if DEBUG` has nothing to do on a debugger is attached or not. With `#if DEBUG` you can include code on debug builds which will be removed on release builds. _(build configuration)_